# No idea why setUpAll() is not running before test()

Tags: flutter

I followed this tutorial https://betterprogramming.pub/flutter-unit-testing-the-beginners-guide-35105164722e for the implementation of setUpAll(){}

Initial code is able to pass flutter test but not the one implemented with setUpAll().

Based on flutter code documentation of the function setUpAll(), this function will run before test(), so in theory, _taskProvider should be initialized, but it doesnt seem like that is the case for my program.

The error shows:

```
test task provider test addTask [E]                                                                                                                      
  LateInitializationError: Local '_taskProvider' has not been initialized.
  dart:_internal                     LateError._throwLocalNotInitialized
  test/task_provider_test.dart 22:7  main.<fn>.<fn>
```

// Code without setUpAll()

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app_new/providers/task_provider.dart';

void main() {
  group("test task provider", () {
    test('test addTask', () {
      TaskProvider _taskProvider = TaskProvider();
      Task _task = Task(title: "MY TO DO ITEM #1", description: "GET GOOD");

      _taskProvider.addTask(_task);

      expect(_task.title, _taskProvider.items[0].title);
      expect(_task.description, _taskProvider.items[0].description);
    });
  });
}
```

// Code with setUpAll()

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app_new/providers/task_provider.dart';

late TaskProvider _taskProvider;
late Task _task;
void main() {
  group("test task provider", () {
    setUpAll() {
      _taskProvider = TaskProvider();
      _task = Task(title: "MY TO DO ITEM #1", description: "GET GOOD");
    }

      test('test addTask', () {
      _taskProvider.addTask(_task);

      expect(_task.title, _taskProvider.items[0].title);
      expect(_task.description, _taskProvider.items[0].description);
    });
  });
}
```

// task_provider.dart file

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class Task {
  bool completed;
  String title;
  String description;
  final String uuid;

  Task({this.completed = false, required this.title, required this.description})
      : uuid = const Uuid().v4();

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant Task other) => uuid == other.uuid;
  @override
  int get hashCode => uuid.hashCode;

  setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
}

class TaskProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Task> _items = [];

  findTask(Task task) {
    _items.firstWhere((i) => i.uuid == task.uuid);

  }

  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get items => UnmodifiableListView(_items);

  void addTask(Task task) {
    _items.add(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see in the original article - setupAll is used in a different way. this is a built-in function that requires a single argument - a function you provide to initialize everything:

```
 setUpAll(() {
    area = Area();
  });
```

How you defined it in your example - you are not calling setUpAll function - but you declare a new function called setUpAll - and you never actually call it.

The idea is to run setupUpAll outside of your test. You should fix it like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app_new/providers/task_provider.dart';

late TaskProvider _taskProvider;
late Task _task;
void main() {

    setUpAll(() {
      _taskProvider = TaskProvider();
      _task = Task(title: "MY TO DO ITEM #1", description: "GET GOOD");
    });

  group("test task provider", () {
    

      test('test addTask', () {
      _taskProvider.addTask(_task);

      expect(_task.title, _taskProvider.items[0].title);
      expect(_task.description, _taskProvider.items[0].description);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the typo.  However, there's nothing wrong with calling [`setUpAll`](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_core/latest/test_core.scaffolding/setUpAll.html) within `group`; it registers a callback that runs before executing the tests in that group.

Comment: I agree; it can be used even within the group. I just find the code more readable if it is outside, but I think this is just an individual preference.

Comment: Omg thank you so much!! I can't believe i was stuck on this typo for hours... Have been trying to search online for similar problem but to no avail, now it make sense that nobody else had this problem..

Comment: I actually realized from your example that @override annotation does not work on top level functions; I also would not catch it in my code; assuming compiler would tell me that I'm trying to override the existing function.